# Unique index violation

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, unique-index

I have a table with following structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Photos](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OriginalUrl] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,
    [ObjCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ImageId] [int] NOT NULL
```

and one of the indexes is:

```
   CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Photos_ObjCode_ProvCode_ImageId] ON 
[dbo].[Photos]
(
    [ObjCode] ASC,
    [ProviderCode] ASC,
    [ImageId] ASC
)
```

The general architecture is:

- web api - responsible for handling incoming request and returning data stored in database or sending requests to queue if there is no data
- 60 instances of handlers which are consuming queue, processing requests and storing the data in db

I get many exceptions when a handler instance tries to insert data which shouldn't violate the uniqueness of data. For example I get following error:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Photos' with unique index 'IX_Photos_ObjCode_ProvCode_ImageId'. The duplicate key value is (ART345, 2625, 0).

when I try to insert set of items with different parameters, for example "PKM6778,8976,0" (ObjCode, ProvCode, ImageId)

It is not possible to reproduce this bug while debugging or working with single handler instance. The logs show also that none of the sets contains any item which could violate this index

Stack: asp .net core 2.2, EF Core 2.0, MSSQL 2008

Answer (score 0):

I think you have bug in your handler code, may be some variables are not thread-safe, for example class-level instead of function-level. You should inspect your code.